# test if a certain type of file exists

Tags: bash, shell, file

I have a script in bash that is supposed to classify all the text files of my working directory and put them in specified directories. It works fine but once used, I get this error message when I try to use it again :

```
ls: cannot access '*.txt': No such file or directory
```

I understand that is it basically because I have no longer any text files in my working directory, but what I'd like to do then is to be able to check first if any '.txt' file exist in my current directory before doing anything else in my script, so that instead of having this message I just exit the script.

I know it can be done for a specific file with this :

```
FILE=/myfile.txt
if test -f "$FILE"; then
    ...
else 
     exit 1
fi
```

But i'd like to do it with any file ending with ".txt"

Comment: The meaning of the last sentence is unclear to me.

Comment: Basically it means any text file, which means ending with '.txt'

Answer (score 1):

You could use null globbing, but stat can do the job too:

```
if stat -t -- *.txt >/dev/null; then
    echo 'found text files'
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the problem by using the `nullglob` option.  For example:

```
shopt -s nullglob

for txtfile in *.txt ; do
    # Put code for classifying "$txtfile" here
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` causes glob patterns (e.g. `*.txt`) that match nothing to expand to nothing.
- `for txtfile in *.txt ...` will execute the body of the loop for every `.txt` file in the current directory.  With `nullglob` enabled, it will do nothing if there are no `.txt` files in the directory.